# hive update a table column with select from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, hql

All,
Is this possible in hive and if so what this the most optimal way? Thanks!

```
    UPDATE t1
    SET
    Y = SQRT(Y_w)*(Y-(SELECT v FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)),
    X1 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X1-(SELECT v1 FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)),
    X2 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X2-(SELECT v2 FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)),
    X3 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X3-(SELECT v3 FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)),
    X4 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X4-(SELECT v4 FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)),
    X5 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X5-(SELECT v5 FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)),
    X6 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X6-(SELECT v6 FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)),
    X7 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X7-(SELECT v7 FROM t2 WHERE ID=1)),
    X8 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X8-(SELECT v8 FROM t2 WHERE ID=1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your query ones.
it will work only if t1 has w column and t2 has id column.